# Having trouble Deserializing json to FHIR Appointment Instance

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, json-deserialization, hl7-fhir

I am obtaining the following json:

```
{
  "fullUrl": "https://my.fhir-server.com:8181/multi-m2integrationtest/firm/xyz123/ema/fhir/v2/Appointment/7240",
  "resource": {
    "resourceType": "Appointment",
    "id": "7240",
    "meta": {
      "lastUpdated": "2020-11-16T15:00:40-05:00"
    },
    "status": "pending",
    "appointmentType": {
      "coding": [
        {
          "system": "https://my.fhir-server.com:8181/multi-m2integrationtest/firm/xyz123/ema/fhir/v2/ValueSet/appointment-type",
          "code": "599",
          "display": "New Patient"
        }
      ],
      "text": "New Patient"
    },
    "reasonCode": [
      {
        "coding": [
          {
            "system": "https://my.fhir-server.com:8181/multi-m2integrationtest/firm/xyz123/ema/fhir/v2/ValueSet/reportable-reason",
            "code": "Other",
            "display": "OTHER"
          }
        ],
        "text": "OTHER"
      }
    ],
    "supportingInformation": [
      {
        "identifier": {
          "system": "NEW_PATIENT",
          "value": "true"
        },
        "display": "New Patient: true"
      }
    ],
    "start": "2020-11-17T09:55:00-05:00",
    "end": "2020-11-17T10:10:00-05:00",
    "minutesDuration": 15,
    "created": "2020-11-16T15:00:40-05:00",
    "participant": [
      {
        "actor": {
          "reference": "https://my.fhir-server.com:8181/multi-m2integrationtest/firm/xyz123/ema/fhir/v2/Location/271",
          "display": "https://my.fhir-server.com:8181/multi-m2integrationtest/firm/xyz123/ema/fhir/v2/Location/271"
        }
      },
      {
        "actor": {
          "reference": "https://my.fhir-server.com:8181/multi-m2integrationtest/firm/xyz123/ema/fhir/v2/Practitioner/116249",
          "display": "https://my.fhir-server.com:8181/multi-m2integrationtest/firm/xyz123/ema/fhir/v2/Practitioner/116249"
        }
      },
      {
        "actor": {
          "reference": "https://my.fhir-server.com:8181/multi-m2integrationtest/firm/xyz123/ema/fhir/v2/Patient/116453",
          "display": "https://my.fhir-server.com:8181/multi-m2integrationtest/firm/xyz123/ema/fhir/v2/Patient/116453"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is an Appointment structure:

[image]

When I attempt to deserialize this into a FHIR Appointment class, the attempt fails:

```
Appointment a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Appointment>(strAppt, jss);
```

There's no exception, but clearly, this has not been successful:

[image]

The Appointment class is instantiated, but all of its attributes are null or 0

Here are the FHIR packages which I have incorporated into my project:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is not to use JsonConvert, but rather to use the specialized FhirJsonParser.

This works:

```
FhirJsonParser fjp = new FhirJsonParser();
Bundle bundle = fjp.Parse<Bundle>(Response);
foreach (var entry in bundle.Entry)
{
    Appointment appt = (Appointment)entry.Resource;
}
```

A good documentation resource: https://docs.fire.ly/firelynetsdk/start.html